# I just ran cat /dev/zero and now cat is hanging

Tags: command-line, cat

I ran `cat /dev/zero` and it now just hangs whenever I run a cat command. I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop that command.

Have I broken something, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you made sure that you have killed all `cat` processes?

Comment: I have, but I think that someone has posted a better answer to mine.

Comment: Tim, After pressing `Ctrl + C` did `cat` stop ? It should work..

Comment: Hmmm..interesting..should work..tested it to be sure..working for me..were you able to use the same shell again after pressing `Ctrl + C` ?

Comment: @heemayl yeah, I was this time :/ now im confused. I guess I panicked and it was actually fine. :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/dev/zero` returns infinitely 0-bytes. The process will never end.

You need to identify the `cat` process and kill it with for example `pkill`:

```
pkill -f 'cat /dev/zero'
```

Answer (score 2):

This is likely to be caused by the `cat` process failing to exit, so to remedy the situation you should make sure that you have killed all `cat` processes.